# Deploy shiny app and report.Rmd file

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I was hoping that somebody could help me with my problem.
I have used [this code](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/016-knitr-pdf) to have download option in my shiny app.

I have modified the  report.Rmd file as following :

````
---
title:
classoption: landscape
header-includes: 
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} 
   \rhead{AEP report - \today}
   \usepackage{eurosym} 
   \usepackage{booktabs,xcolor}
   \setlength\headheight{28pt}
   \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{C:path to my logo.png}}
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{All rights received }
output: pdf_document
---
\ 

```{r, fig.align='center', fig.pos='htb!',out.width="900px", echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
DT::datatable(main()$AEP, options = list(dom='t',ordering=F,rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '100px')}")))


```
````

App is running on my local pc, but when I put it on shinyapps.io, is still running and show the result but the download part returns error !!

I have searched a lot for a solution and I did not find any !
I really appreciate if someone could help me on that ! 
I know the problem is Rmd file, but I don't know how to fix it.